# Importing from relative path in python syntax error

Tags: python

I am trying to import from relative path in my python program.

the class i would like to import is in

```
home/foo/bar/model.py
```

However, my current python script is in

```
home/best/user/test.py
```

i have tried to use

```
from ../../foo/bar import class
```

But it throws up a syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When importing modules, python looks in the current working directory and in the paths in `sys.path`. You can add the directory of the script you would like to import to `sys.path`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('home/foo/bar')
import model # imports home/foo/bar/model.py
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that.  You can't import from an explicitly specified path (without awful trickery).  All Python imports are based on the systemwide import paths (in `sys,path`).  You can't import anything that isn't reachable from `sys,path` (i.e., it's either on `sys.path` itself or it's inside a package that's on `sys.path`).  [The documenation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) has the details.  If you want to be able to import from that file, you need to somehow add its directory (or the directory of its topmost containing package) to the path.